# I set up Hadoop successfully in virtual machine but cannot access Hadoop homepage at outside environment, why?

Tags: macos, hadoop, virtual-machine

I set up Hadoop successfully in virtual machine (centOS) but cannot access Hadoop homepage at outside environment, why?

I use MacOS and Parallels as virtual machine.

[image]

Comment: What kind of VM? Virtual box? VMWare? Are you using VArmor?

Comment: @Petro Says Parallels in the question

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities

1. Your DNS settings are not configured on your Mac host to know how to communicate with `kfk.com`
2. You're not exposing or forwarding port 50700 outside the firewall of that domain, or virtual machine

You can do port forwarding in Parallels Preferences > Advanced > Network: Change Settings > Shared